# Ncurses issue around functions which print to a window

Tags: c++, linux, ncurses

I'm currently making a simple ncurses menu for executing terminal commands more quickly while working on projects. I'm new to the library and keep having the same issue. I've read the documentation for the relevant functions but it seems to reveal nothing. I was hoping someone more experienced would know why there's an issue.

The function which performs "make main" has been the main one causing the problems

```
void makeMain( WINDOW *window ) {

    wrefresh(window);
    mvwprintw( window, 1, 1, "test" ); 
    wrefresh(window);

    std::system("make main");
    wrefresh(window);
    refresh();

    wmove( window, 1, 1 ); 
    refresh();
    wrefresh( window ); 

}
```

the function is run from another function

```
void coordinateUserInput( int max, std::vector<command> commandslist, WINDOW *output ) {

    cbreak();
    noecho();

    wrefresh(stdscr);

    //prep work

    char key_pressed;

    bool can_go_up;
    bool can_go_down;

    int y;
    int x;

    const int &start_line = 3;
    const int &finish_line = commandslist.size() + 2;

    bool keep_going{1};
    //

    wmove( stdscr, 3, 2 );
    refresh();

    while(keep_going) {

        getyx( stdscr, y, x );

        can_go_up = (!(y == start_line));
        can_go_down = (!(y == finish_line));

        key_pressed = getch();

        switch(key_pressed) {

            case 'j':
                if(can_go_down) {
                    wmove( stdscr, y + 1, 2 );
                    refresh();
                }
                break;

            case 'k':
                if(can_go_up) {
                    wmove( stdscr, y - 1, 2 );
                    refresh();
                }
                break;

            case '\n':
                ((commandslist[y - 3]).fcnpointer)(output);
                wmove( stdscr, 3, 2 );
                refresh();
                break;

            case 'q':
                keep_going = 0;
                break;

            default:
                break;

        }

    }

    return;

}
```

I'm fairly certain that these would be the problem functions. Running with `-Wall` and `-Wextra` doesn't yield errors.

```
int main() {

    bool *is_set_up = new bool;

    initscr();
    refresh();

    //set up command ouput window pointer
    int maxx;
    int *maxy = new int;

    getmaxyx(stdscr, *maxy, maxx);

    delete maxy;

    static WINDOW *command_output = newwin( 3, maxx, 0, 0 ); 
    box(command_output, 0, 0);
    wrefresh(command_output);

    // 


    std::vector<command> commands = {defineCommands()};

    writeMenu(commands, commands.size(), is_set_up);
    refresh();

    coordinateUserInput(commands.size()-1, commands, command_output);

    std::cout << "worked" << std::endl;

    endwin();

    delete is_set_up;


    return 0; 

}
```

[image]

Comment: Please use the `edit` link in the question, right below the tags, to edit your question to include crucial details.

Comment: I am worried that I couldn't explain the issue very well with words. Would it be helpful to give you the object file so you can see the output yourself?

Comment: @Pugpugpugs no, don't do that. Don't dump whole programs here, especially not via external resources. Ideal would be to create a [MCVE]. Also **you haven't mention what the problem actually is!**

Comment: You don't state what the problem is so it is hard to help you. Nonetheless, what you're trying to achieve requires way more than what you actually wrote: opening pseudo tty and ensuring the full-duplex communication with the other process, handling signals, waiting for child process, and so on... You'd better use a terminal multiplexer like tmux or screen.

Comment: A terminal multiplexer does seem like a good idea. I can try to explain the issue from the code and from the screenshot. What I am trying to do is move the cursor to the window "window" and print the result of the command "make main." When this is finished, I am trying to move back to the list of three items and re enable selection from this list. The problem I keep encountering is that when I move back to the list (which exists in window "stdscr") the cursor is then moved to the right by the number of characters which I printed in the "window" window regardless of what x coordinate I give it.

Comment: Your example is incomplete (not a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).  In particular, it gives no clue regarding the windows which are passed to `makeMain`.

Comment: added the main function, which generates the relevant window. tell me if you need anything else.